# How we can utilize resize method in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, visual-web-developer-2010

I am a noob in javascript so anyone please help me, When I zoomed in on the image and if the mouse out from that image it will return its original size how we did that through resize method that given in "imageviewer2.js".
The image is zoomed in million times but when the mouse cursor is out from the image div it will not return its original size how we can do it by resize method.

I did that mouseout method but that is a patchwork so I want with the resize method but I can't understand how I can do that from resize method.

```js
/*
 * imgViewer2
 * 
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Wayne Mogg
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 */



var waitForFinalEvent = (function () {
 var timers = {};
 return function (callback, ms, uniqueId) {
  if (!uniqueId) {
   uniqueId = "Don't call this twice without a uniqueId";
  }
  if (timers[uniqueId]) {
   clearTimeout (timers[uniqueId]);
  }
  timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
 };
})();
/*
 * imgViewer2 plugin starts here
 */
;(function($) {
 $.widget("wgm.imgViewer2", {
  options: {
   zoomStep: 0.5,
   zoomMax: undefined,
   zoomable: true,
   dragable: true,
   onClick: $.noop,
   onReady: $.noop
  },
  
  _create: function() {
   var self = this;
   if (!$(this.element).is("img")) {
                var elem = this.element.children()[0];
                if (!$(elem).is("img")) {
                    $.error('imgviewer plugin can only be applied to img elements');
                } else {
                    self.img = self.element.children()[0];
                }
            } else {
                self.img = self.element[0];
   }
//  the original img element
   var $img = $(self.img);
/*
 *  a copy of the original image to be positioned over it and manipulated to
 *  provide zoom and pan
 */
   self.view = $("<div class='viewport' />").uniqueId().appendTo($img.parent());
   var $view = $(self.view);
   self.map  = {};
   self.bounds = {};
//  a flag used to check the target image has loaded
   self.ready = false;
   self.resize = false;
   $img.one("load",function() {
//   get and some geometry information about the image
    self.ready = true;
    var width = $img.width(),
     height = $img.height(),
     offset = $img.position();
//   cache the image padding information
     self.offsetPadding = {
       top: parseInt($img.css('padding-top'),10),
       left: parseInt($img.css('padding-left'),10),
       right: parseInt($img.css('padding-right'),10),
       bottom: parseInt($img.css('padding-bottom'),10)
     };
/*
 *   cache the image margin/border size information
 *   because of IE8 limitations left and right borders are assumed to be the same width 
 *   and likewise top and bottom borders
 */
     self.offsetBorder = {
       x: Math.round(($img.outerWidth()-$img.innerWidth())/2),
       y: Math.round(($img.outerHeight()-$img.innerHeight())/2)
     };
/*
 *   define the css style for the view container using absolute positioning to
 *   put it directly over the original image
 */
     var vTop = offset.top + self.offsetBorder.y + self.offsetPadding.top,
      vLeft = offset.left + self.offsetBorder.x + self.offsetPadding.left;

     $view.css({
        position: "absolute",
        overflow: "hidden",
        top: vTop+"px",
        left: vLeft+"px",
        width: width+"px",
        height: height+"px"
     });
//   add the leaflet map
     self.bounds = L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(0,0), L.latLng(self.img.naturalHeight,self.img.naturalWidth));
     self.map = L.map($view.attr('id'), {crs:L.CRS.Simple,
              minZoom: -10,
              trackresize: false,
              maxBoundsViscosity: 1.0,
              attributionControl: false,
              inertia: false,
              zoomSnap: 0,
              wheelPxPerZoomLevel: Math.round(36/self.options.zoomStep),
              zoomDelta: self.options.zoomStep
     });
     self.zimg = L.imageOverlay(self.img.src, self.bounds).addTo(self.map);
     self.map.options.minZoom = self.map.getBoundsZoom(self.bounds,false);
     self.map.fitBounds(self.bounds);
     self.bounds = self.map.getBounds();
     self.map.setMaxBounds(self.bounds);
     if (self.options.zoomMax !== null) {
      var lzoom = self.leafletZoom(self.options.zoomMax);
      if (lzoom < self.map.getZoom()) {
       self.map.setZoom(lzoom);
      }
      self.map.options.maxZoom = lzoom;
     }
     if (!self.options.dragable) {
      self.map.dragging.disable();
     }
     if (!self.options.zoomable) {
      self.map.zoomControl.disable();
      self.map.boxZoom.disable();
      self.map.touchZoom.disable();
      self.map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
      self.map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
     }
     self.map.on('click', function(ev) {
      if (self.options.onClick !== null) {
       self.options.onClick.call(self, ev.originalEvent, self.eventToImg(ev));
      }
     });
     self.map.on('zoomend', function() {
      if (self.options.zoomMax >= 1 && this.getZoom() > this.options.zoomMax) {
       this.setZoom(this.options.zoomMax);
      }
      if (!self.resize) {
       self.bounds = self.map.getBounds();
      }
     });
     self.map.on('moveend', function() {
      if (!self.resize) {
       self.bounds = self.map.getBounds();
      }
     });
     self.map.on('resize', function() {
      self.map.options.minZoom = -10;
      self.map.fitBounds(self.bounds,{animate:false});
      self.map.options.minZoom = self.map.getBoundsZoom(L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(0,0), L.latLng(self.img.naturalHeight,self.img.naturalWidth)),true);
      self.map.options.maxZoom = self.leafletZoom(self.options.zoomMax);
      waitForFinalEvent(function(){
       self.resize = false;
       self._view_resize();
       self.map.options.minZoom = -10;
       self.map.fitBounds(self.bounds,{animate:false});
       self.map.options.minZoom = self.map.getBoundsZoom(L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(0,0), L.latLng(self.img.naturalHeight,self.img.naturalWidth)),true);
       self.map.options.maxZoom = self.leafletZoom(self.options.zoomMax);
      }, 300, $img[0].id);
     });
     self.options.onReady.call(self);
   }).each(function() {
    if (this.complete) { $(this).trigger("load"); }
   });
/*
/*
 *  Window resize handler
 */
   $(window).resize(function() {
    if (self.ready) {
     self.resize = true;
     self._view_resize();
     self.map.invalidateSize({animate: false});
    }
   });
  },
/*
 * View resize - the aim is to keep the view centered on the same location in the original image
 */
  _view_resize: function() {
   if (this.ready) {
    var $view = $(this.view),
     $img = $(this.img),
     width = $img.width(),
     height = $img.height(),
     offset = $img.position(),
     vTop = Math.round(offset.top + this.offsetBorder.y + this.offsetPadding.top),
     vLeft = Math.round(offset.left + this.offsetBorder.x + this.offsetPadding.left);
    $view.css({
       top: vTop+"px",
       left: vLeft+"px",
       width: width+"px",
       height: height+"px"
    });
   }
  },
/*
 * Remove the plugin
 */  
  destroy: function() {
   $(window).unbind("resize");
   this.map.remove();
   $(this.view).remove();
   $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
  },
  
  _setOption: function(key, value) {
   switch(key) {
    case 'zoomStep':
     if (parseFloat(value) <= 0 ||  isNaN(parseFloat(value))) {
      return;
     }
     break;
    case 'zoomMax':
     if (parseFloat(value) < 1 || isNaN(parseFloat(value))) {
      return;
     }
     break;
   }
   var version = $.ui.version.split('.');
   if (version[0] > 1 || version[1] > 8) {
    this._super(key, value);
   } else {
    $.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply(this, arguments);
   }
   switch(key) {
    case 'zoomStep':
     if (this.ready) {
      this.map.options.zoomDelta = this.options.zoomStep;
      this.map.options.wheelPxPerZoomLevel = Math.round(60/this.options.zoomStep);
     }
     break;
    case 'zoomMax':
     if (this.ready) {
      lzoom = this.leafletZoom(this.options.zoomMax);
      if (lzoom < this.map.getZoom()) {
       this.map.setZoom(lzoom);
      }
      this.map.options.maxZoom = lzoom;
      this.map.fire('zoomend');
     }
     break;
    case 'zoomable':
     if (this.options.zoomable) {
      this.map.zoomControl.enable();
      this.map.boxZoom.enable();
      this.map.touchZoom.enable();
      this.map.doubleClickZoom.enable();
      this.map.scrollWheelZoom.enable();
     } else {
      this.map.zoomControl.disable();
      this.map.boxZoom.disable();
      this.map.touchZoom.disable();
      this.map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
      this.map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
     }
     break;
    case 'dragable':
     if (this.options.dragable) {
      this.map.dragging.enable();
     } else {
      this.map.dragging.disable();
     }
     break;
   }
  },
/*
 * Test if a relative image coordinate is visible in the current view
 */
  isVisible: function(relx, rely) {
   var view = this.getView();
   if (view) {
    return (relx >= view.left && relx <= view.right && rely >= view.top && rely <= view.bottom);
   } else {
    return false;
   }
  },
/*
 * Convert a user supplied zoom to a Leaflet zoom
*/
  leafletZoom: function(zoom) {
   if (this.ready && zoom !== undefined) {
    var img = this.img,
     map = this.map,
     lzoom = map.getZoom() || 0,
     size = map.getSize(),
     width = img.naturalWidth,
     height = img.naturalHeight,
     nw = L.latLng(height/zoom,width/zoom),
     se = L.latLng(0,0),
     boundsSize = map.project(nw, lzoom).subtract(map.project(se, lzoom));

    var scale = Math.min(size.x / boundsSize.x, -size.y / boundsSize.y);
    return map.getScaleZoom(scale, lzoom);
   } else {
    return undefined;
   }
  },
/*
 * Get the Leaflet map object
*/
  getMap: function() {
   if (this.ready) {
    return this.map;
   }
   else {
    return null;
   }
  },
/*
 * Get current zoom level
 * Returned zoom will always be >=1
 * a zoom of 1 means the entire image is just visible within the viewport
 * a zoom of 2 means half the image is visible in the viewport etc
*/
  getZoom: function() {
   if (this.ready) {
    var img = this.img,
     map = this.map,
     width = img.naturalWidth,
     height = img.naturalHeight,
     constraint = this.options.constraint,
     bounds = map.getBounds();
    if (constraint == 'width' ) {
     return Math.max(1, width/(bounds.getEast()-bounds.getWest()));
    } else if (constraint == 'height') {
     return Math.max(1,height/(bounds.getNorth()-bounds.getSouth()));
    } else {
     return Math.max(1, (width/(bounds.getEast()-bounds.getWest()) + height/(bounds.getNorth()-bounds.getSouth()))/2);
    }
   } else {
    return null;
   }
  },
/*
 * Set the zoom level
 * Zoom must be >=1
 * a zoom of 1 means the entire image is just visible within the viewport
 * a zoom of 2 means half the image is visible in the viewport etc
*/
  setZoom: function( zoom ) {
   if (this.ready) {
    zoom = Math.max(1, zoom);
    if (this.options.zoomMax === undefined) {
    } else {
     zoom = Math.min(zoom, this.options.zoomMax);
    }
    var img = this.img,
     map = this.map,
     width = img.naturalWidth,
     height = img.naturalHeight,
     constraint = this.options.constraint,
     center = map.getCenter(),
     bounds = map.getBounds();
    var hvw, hvh;
    if (constraint == 'width') {
     hvw = width/zoom/2;
     hvh = hvw * (bounds.getNorth()-bounds.getSouth())/(bounds.getEast()-bounds.getWest());
    } else if (constraint == 'height') {
     hvh = height/zoom/2;
     hvw = hvh * (bounds.getEast()-bounds.getWest())/(bounds.getNorth()-bounds.getSouth());
    } else {
     hvw = width/zoom/2;
     hvh = height/zoom/2;
    }
      
    var east = center.lng + hvw,
     west = center.lng - hvw,
     north = center.lat + hvh,
     south = center.lat - hvh;
    if (west<0) {
     east += west;
     west = 0;
    } else if (east > width) {
     west -= east-width;
     east = width;
    }
    if (south<0) {
     north += south;
     south = 0;
    } else if (north > height) {
     south -= north-height;
     north = height;
    }
    map.fitBounds(L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(south,west), L.latLng(north,east)),{animate:false});
   }
   return this;
  },
/*
 * Get relative image coordinates of current view
 */
  getView: function() {
   if (this.ready) {
    var img = this.img,
     width = img.naturalWidth,
     height = img.naturalHeight,
     bnds = this.map.getBounds();
    return {
     top: 1 - bnds.getNorth()/height,
     left: bnds.getWest()/width,
     bottom: 1 - bnds.getSouth()/height,
     right: bnds.getEast()/width
    };
   } else {
    return null;
   }
  },
/*
 * Pan the view to be centred at the given relative image location
 */
  panTo: function(relx, rely) {
   if ( this.ready && relx >= 0 && relx <= 1 && rely >= 0 && rely <=1 ) {
    var img = this.img,
     map = this.map,
     bounds = this.bounds,
//     bounds = map.getBounds(),
     east = bounds.getEast(),
     west = bounds.getWest(),
     north = bounds.getNorth(),
     south = bounds.getSouth(),
     centerX = (east+west)/2,
     centerY = (north+south)/2,
     width = img.naturalWidth,
     height = img.naturalHeight,
     newY = (1-rely)*height,
     newX = relx*width;
    east += newX - centerX;
    west += newX - centerX;
    north += newY - centerY;
    south += newY - centerY;
                if (west<0) {
                    east -= west;
                    west = 0;
                }
                if (east > width) {
                    west -= east-width;
                    east = width;
                }
                if (south<0) {
                    north -= south;
                    south = 0;
                }
                if (north > height) {
                    south -= north-height;
                    north = height;
                }
                map.fitBounds(L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(south,west), L.latLng(north,east)),{animate:false});
   }
   return this;
  },
/*
 * Return the relative image coordinate for a Leaflet event 
 */  
  eventToImg: function(ev) {
   if (this.ready) {
    var img = this.img,
     width = img.naturalWidth,
     height = img.naturalHeight;
    relx = ev.latlng.lng/width;
    rely = 1 - ev.latlng.lat/height;
    if (relx>=0 && relx<=1 && rely>=0 && rely<=1) {
     return {x: relx, y: rely};
    } else {
     return null;
    }
   } else {
    return null;
   }
  },
/*
 * Convert relative image coordinate to Leaflet LatLng point
 */
  relposToLatLng: function(x,y) {
   if (this.ready) {
    var img = this.img,
     width = img.naturalWidth,
     height = img.naturalHeight;
    return L.latLng((1-y)*height, x*width);
   } else {
    return null;
   }
  },
/*
 * Convert relative image coordinate to Image pixel
 */
  relposToImage: function(pos) {
   if (this.ready) {
    var img = this.img,
     width = img.naturalWidth,
     height = img.naturalHeight;
    return {x: Math.round(pos.x*width), y: Math.round(pos.y*height)};
   } else {
    return null;
   }
  }
 });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>imgViewer2 Plugin - custom onClick callback example</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/imgViewer2.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 100%; min-width: 320px;">
   <tr>
   <td style="padding: 10px">
    <h1 align="center">imgViewer2 Plugin - custom onClick callback example</h1>
    <div align="center">
     <img  id="image1" src="https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/laughing-black-man-wearing-backpack-near-purple-door-picture-id573064079" style="border: 30px solid #555; padding:20px;" width="80%"  />
    </div>
    <p style="margin:10px 5% 10px 5%;text-align: justify;"> 
    This example demonstrates the widget with a custom "onClick" callback. In this case clicking on the image will show the page pixel coordinates, image pixel coordinates and relative image coordinates (relative image coordinates range from 0,0 to 1,1 where 0,0 is the top-left corner and 1,1 is the bottom-right corner of the image) in a modal dialog.
    </p>
    <p style="margin:10px 5% 10px 5%;text-align: justify;">
    Zoom in and out using the mousewheel, +/- controls, double click/tap or hold the shift key and drag out a rectangle. Left mouseclick and drag to pan. On touch enable devices pinch gestures can be used to zoom in and out and tap and drag to pan around.
    </p>    
    <p style="margin:10px 5% 10px 5%;">Resize the window and try again</p>    
   </td>
   </tr>
  </table>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   ;(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
     var $img = $("#image1").imgViewer2({
        onReady: function() {
         $('.leaflet-grab').css('cursor','crosshair');
        },
        onClick: function( e, pos ) {
         var $message = $("<div id='dialog-modal'></div>").dialog({
              modal: true,
              title: "You clicked at:",
              open: function(ev, ui) {
               $('.ui-dialog').css('z-index',2001);
               $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('z-index',2000);
              }
         });
         var imgpos = this.relposToImage(pos);
         $message.html("Page X: " + e.pageX + "<br/>Page Y: " + e.pageY + "<br/>Image Pixel X: " + imgpos.x + "<br/>Image Pixel Y: " + imgpos.y + "<br/>Image Rel X: " + pos.x.toFixed(3) + "<br/>Image Rel Y: " + pos.y.toFixed(3));
        }
     });
    });
   })(jQuery);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```